# Show *only* docstring in Sphinx documentation?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

Sphinx has a feature called `automethod` that extracts the documentation from a method's docstring and embeds that into the documentation. But it not only embeds the docstring, but also the method signature (name + arguments). How do I embed *only* the docstring (excluding the method signature)?

ref: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
from sphinx.ext import autodoc

class DocsonlyMethodDocumenter(autodoc.MethodDocumenter):
  def format_args(self):
    return None

autodoc.add_documenter(DocsonlyMethodDocumenter)
```

per [the current sources](http://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/tip/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py) this should allow overriding what class is responsible for documenting methods (older versions of `add_documenter` forbade such overrides, but now they're explicitly allowed).  Having `format_args` return None, of course, is THE documented way in `autodoc` to say "don't bother with the signature".

I think this is the clean, architected way to perform this task, and, as such, preferable to monkeypatching alternatives. If you need to live with some old versions of `sphinx` however you may indeed have to monkeypatch (`autodoc.MethodDocumenter.format_args=lambda _:None` -- eek!-) though I would recommend upgrading `sphinx` to the current version as a better approach if at all feasible in your specific deployment.

Comment: +1 In Sphinx 1.1 there is a minor syntax change in adding a documenter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825263/including-docstring-in-sphinx-documentation