# Including docstring in Sphinx Documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'd like to include just the docstring of a specific function in my Sphinx documentation. However there seem to be no options to just display these details without associated class and function definitions using http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html

I've tried creating a class as outlined in [Show *only* docstring in Sphinx documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370283/show-only-docstring-in-sphinx-documentation) but I'm not sure how this fits in with the templating.

I've also tried the autodoc-process-docstring event handler with no luck.

So rather than my documentation displaying (as it is currently):

```
class module.MyClass(param)

    This is the class doc string

    my_method()

        This is my method doc string
```

I just want to display:

```
This is my method doc string
```

My current template in a .txt file is:

```
.. autoclass:: module.MyClass
    :members: my_method
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After looking through the source and experimenting - here is how to do it in Sphinx 1.1.

In your conf.py file create a new MethodDocumenter subclass. Here you can set a new "objtype", make sure the docstring is not indented, and remove the title.

```
from sphinx.ext import autodoc

class SimpleDocumenter(autodoc.MethodDocumenter):
    objtype = "simple"

    #do not indent the content
    content_indent = ""

    #do not add a header to the docstring
    def add_directive_header(self, sig):
        pass
```

Then make sure this is added to the available documenters with the following function (again in conf.py):

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_autodocumenter(SimpleDocumenter)
```

Then when you just want to display a method's docstring use the following format in your .txt or .rst files. Just prefix your objname with auto.

```
.. autosimple:: mod.MyClass.my_method
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach with Sphinx 5.3.

If you don't want to override the default MethodDocumenter for your class API documentation, you need to also override the following `can_document_member` and set it to False. The resulting class looks as follows

```
class SimpleDocumenter(autodoc.MethodDocumenter):
"""
Reference a class or method docstring only.
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7832437/5726546
"""
  objtype = "simple"

    content_indent = ""

    @classmethod
    def can_document_member(cls, member: Any, membername: str, isattr: bool, parent: Any) -> bool:
        return False

    # do not add a header to the docstring
    def add_directive_header(self, sig: str) -> None:
        pass
```

Setup and directive are the same as in the [answer by geographika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7832437/5726546).